# Changed behavior in object field access in Groovy 3.0?

Tags: groovy, operators

I've recently stumbled on this issue when assisting in the migration of some legacy code.

The following used to execute correctly in Groovy 2.4.x :

```
class Person {
  String name
}

def me = new Person( name : 'Joe' )

assert me.(name) == 'Joe'
```

while it raises an exception when executed on Groovy 3.0.2 :

***groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: name for class: MyScript***

Enclosing the property name in parentheses actually looks wrong to me: as a matter of fact, I was surprised that an exception was not raised in older releases too.

The syntax I would probably have used is either:

```
assert me.name == 'Joe'
```

or something like:

```
assert me.'name' == 'Joe'
```

which work in both versions 2.4 AND 3.0.

I did some research and couldn't find anything in the Changelogs from Groovy 2.4 through Groovy 3.0 that refers to something that could affect this behavior.

Am I missing something here?

Was the fact that the code worked in 2.4 an unexpected behavior, which has been corrected?
Or is this actually expected to work?

My guess is that it has to do with the switch to the new Parrot parser in version 3.0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you wrap the property name in parens, like "me.(name)", you are using dynamic property syntax.  Groovy is supposed to resolve "name" in the enclosing scope and not against the receiver.  If you want to get the "name" property from "me", you can write "me.name" or "me.'name'" or "me['name']" or "me.getProperty('name')".

Comment: Thanks emilles, that is exactly what I was expecting too. But from my tests, I've seen that it works as you describe only for Groovy 3.0+. On earlier versions, "me.(name)" seems to be the treated as an equivalent of "me.'name'" or "me.name", regardless of whether a variable "name" exists or not in the enclosing scope. I am trying to understand if anyone can confirm this different behavior and if it is documented anywhere.

Comment: It is mentioned in the parser grammar which is the only reason I am aware of it. When I discovered it and tried it out I found it didn't work as I expected. It may be a legacy feature and the new parser in Groovy 3 fixed this old construct.

Comment: Do you happen to remember where you found the reference in the parser grammar? I could not find anything in the documentation that references this case directly, although the behavior in version 3.0 is what I would be expecting to be correct.

Comment: Here is it as part of a path expression: https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_3_0_X/src/main/antlr2/org/codehaus/groovy/antlr/groovy.g#L2347

And the declaration of dynamicMemberName: https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_3_0_X/src/main/antlr2/org/codehaus/groovy/antlr/groovy.g#L2413

This is the antlr2 grammar (not used by default in Groovy 3) but the antlr4 grammar was based off this.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the references in the grammar, my feeling is that the behavior was indeed unexpected in 2.4 and was fixed in Groovy 3.0.